# Values in the array are being overrwritten

Tags: javascript, arrays

The value in meshEdge is being overwritten by the last value of gemoetry. i have tried things but still the problem remains.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var meshEdges = new Array();
var firstPoint = [];
for (i = 0; i < json.edges.length; i++) {
    firstPoint[i] = json.edges[i].edeVertices;
    positions = new Float32Array([firstPoint[i][0] , firstPoint[i][1], firstPoint[i][2], firstPoint[i][3], firstPoint[i][4], firstPoint[i][5]]);
    geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions,3));
    meshEdges.push(geometry);

    }
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd assume you need to create a new THREE.BufferGeometry in every iteration of the loop. Just bring your top line inside the for.

Comment: Yup..thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing the same `geometry` again and again. Array has a reference to that and when the geometry updated, array values also get updated.
Therfore, each time create a new geometry and push it.

```
 var meshEdges = new Array();
 var firstPoint = [];
 for (i = 0; i < json.edges.length; i++) {
   var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
   firstPoint[i] = json.edges[i].edeVertices;
   positions = new Float32Array([firstPoint[i][0] , firstPoint[i][1], firstPoint[i][2], firstPoint[i][3], firstPoint[i][4], firstPoint[i][5]]);
   geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions,3));
   meshEdges.push(geometry); 
 }
```